# Double variable get its value from EditText

Tags: java, android

i have been learning java for 4 days and i wonder if this code is the correct way to do it

```
  vvv = Double.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText().toString()));
```

I think its a lot of words for a simple code

Comment: why are you doing this?

Comment: vvv = Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText().toString());

Comment: I'd guess that that `txt1.getText()` will already be a `String`, no need to call `toString()` on a `String`.

Comment: `txt1.getText()` will be an `Editable`, `toString()` will convert it to `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vvv = Double.valueOf(txt1.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to demonstrate in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are doing well. 
But it is better to wrap it with try & catch because editText value may not contains a valid double (for example dot . ) so it may throw formatException.

```
     try     
       {
         vvv = Double.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText().toString()));            
       } catch (Exception e) {
         vvv = 0 ;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesting the method Double.parseDouble() in Double.valueOf() is redundant as

```
vv = Double.valueOf(<some_string_value>);
```

and

```
vv = Double.parseDouble(<some_string_value>);
```

can be used equivalently in case you are using Java versions 1.5 and later. The reason is that there are two overloaded *valueOf()* methods in the class Double.